# Android datepicker dialog

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

How can I disable the day on a datepicker dialog for android? Meant only the month and year is visible. Currently using android 2.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom date picker with months and years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236389/custom-date-picker-with-months-and-years)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom DatePicker in that case, for exemple refer to this google project that present an  [alternative time and date picker for android](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but prior to I think 4.0 you cant do this, you only have the option for a full date or full time picker.

You could create your own, but this might take a while, have a look at what others have done.. Heres an example of a full date picker, but you could just take the day out of this as it is xml.

[Custom date picker with months and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236389/custom-date-picker-with-months-and-years/9236861#9236861)

Also I think it is a possible duplicate as [Custom date picker with months and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236389/custom-date-picker-with-months-and-years/9236861)

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom date picker using [ready to use framework](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) for this.

The [Dateslider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) is a framework for a range of date picker widgets based on the principle of sliding bars. This results in a very intuitive and enhanced user experience.

Check it out it may produce something like [image] to meet your needs.

Thanks