# How to have a better looking DatePicker?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-datepicker

I have to develop an Android app that needs to be run on 2.2 devices; i'm using HoloEverywhereLib with which the UI is pretty good.
I need to use a DatePicker; if i use the default component, it has a really ugly look:

[image]

I would like to have something like the new one:

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: is this iphone layout in second image ?

Comment: No, it is a sample of 4.0 Android DatePicker

Comment: this may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236389/custom-date-picker-with-months-and-years

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the default datepicker for Android HC+ you could just implement it by copying the code from the [Android github framework mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/app):

You'll need the DatePickerDialog:

```
package.android.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;

import com.android.internal.R;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple dialog containing an {@link android.widget.DatePicker}.
 *
 * <p>See the <a href="{@docRoot}guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html">Pickers</a>
 * guide.</p>
 */
public class DatePickerDialog extends AlertDialog implements OnClickListener,
        OnDateChangedListener {

    private static final String YEAR = "year";
    private static final String MONTH = "month";
    private static final String DAY = "day";

    private final DatePicker mDatePicker;
    private final OnDateSetListener mCallBack;
    private final Calendar mCalendar;

    private boolean mTitleNeedsUpdate = true;

    /**
     * The callback used to indicate the user is done filling in the date.
     */
    public interface OnDateSetListener {

        /**
         * @param view The view associated with this listener.
         * @param year The year that was set.
         * @param monthOfYear The month that was set (0-11) for compatibility
         *  with {@link java.util.Calendar}.
         * @param dayOfMonth The day of the month that was set.
         */
        void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
    }

    /**
     * @param context The context the dialog is to run in.
     * @param callBack How the parent is notified that the date is set.
     * @param year The initial year of the dialog.
     * @param monthOfYear The initial month of the dialog.
     * @param dayOfMonth The initial day of the dialog.
     */
    public DatePickerDialog(Context context,
            OnDateSetListener callBack,
            int year,
            int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        this(context, 0, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    /**
     * @param context The context the dialog is to run in.
     * @param theme the theme to apply to this dialog
     * @param callBack How the parent is notified that the date is set.
     * @param year The initial year of the dialog.
     * @param monthOfYear The initial month of the dialog.
     * @param dayOfMonth The initial day of the dialog.
     */
    public DatePickerDialog(Context context,
            int theme,
            OnDateSetListener callBack,
            int year,
            int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, theme);

        mCallBack = callBack;

        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Context themeContext = getContext();
        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, themeContext.getText(R.string.date_time_done), this);
        setIcon(0);

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) themeContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_dialog, null);
        setView(view);
        mDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, this);
        updateTitle(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        tryNotifyDateSet();
    }

    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
            int month, int day) {
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, this);
        updateTitle(year, month, day);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the {@link DatePicker} contained in this dialog.
     *
     * @return The calendar view.
     */
    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return mDatePicker;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current date.
     *
     * @param year The date year.
     * @param monthOfYear The date month.
     * @param dayOfMonth The date day of month.
     */
    public void updateDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mDatePicker.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    private void tryNotifyDateSet() {
        if (mCallBack != null) {
            mDatePicker.clearFocus();
            mCallBack.onDateSet(mDatePicker, mDatePicker.getYear(),
                    mDatePicker.getMonth(), mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        tryNotifyDateSet();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void updateTitle(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (!mDatePicker.getCalendarViewShown()) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            String title = DateUtils.formatDateTime(mContext,
                    mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE
                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY
                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH
                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_WEEKDAY);
            setTitle(title);
            mTitleNeedsUpdate = true;
        } else {
            if (mTitleNeedsUpdate) {
                mTitleNeedsUpdate = false;
                setTitle(R.string.date_picker_dialog_title);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle onSaveInstanceState() {
        Bundle state = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        state.putInt(YEAR, mDatePicker.getYear());
        state.putInt(MONTH, mDatePicker.getMonth());
        state.putInt(DAY, mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        int year = savedInstanceState.getInt(YEAR);
        int month = savedInstanceState.getInt(MONTH);
        int day = savedInstanceState.getInt(DAY);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, this);
    }
}
```

And the [AltertDialog](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java).

You'll also have to import the resources. You can find them [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res).
And you have to replace the Holo Theme in the AlertDialog with the HoloEverwhere equivalent of the dark and light theme

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the ice cream sandwich styled date picker is by using the [ActionBarSherlock library.](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Then create the dialog class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment implements android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private OnFragmentClickListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement listeners!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        mListener.onFragmentClick(DialogDemonstrationActivity.DATE_PICKER_ACTION, c);
    }
}
```

The activity listener class:

```
public interface OnFragmentClickListener {
    public void onFragmentClick(int action, Object object);
}
```

The dialog can be launched with following from your activity:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                // Create and show the dialog.
                DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(ft, null);
```

Your activity then have to implement the listener and you are up and running.